# Installing packages in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have an application that has a library that depends on libcurl and libopenssl.

Is there a way in cloud foundry to apt-get or install these dependencies without having to package them with my application?

Comment: Which buildpack are you using? libcurl sounds like you are using C. You may consider pushing a docker image?

Comment: It's a Go application that uses CGo for some work.

Does CF support Docker images? I'll have to do more investigation into that.